# Vuetify dialog and visual bug with select input

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

On documentation page of Vuetify https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs, there is an example of dialog Component. You can see the select component get out of the dialog :

[image]

I don't have the same behaviour on my page, I don't understand why :

[image]

You can see my code sample on : https://github.com/aprovin/vuetify-dialog1

Comment: Can you try to remove the `attach` prop from the `v-dialog` to see if it solves your problem?

Comment: I was convinced that the problem was with the vdialog component... But no. It was the attach prop in select component. Thank you very much Charlie !

Comment: @Aurelin I have added an answer. Please, mark it as complete so you can help others solve similar issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `attach` prop in your `v-dialog` component